# Element should have been "select" but was "input" how can I resolve this error

Tags: java

My Code:

```
    loginPage.waitHomePage(60,"Order Scheduling");
    Assert.assertEquals("Order Scheduling",driver.getTitle());

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 40)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input")));
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input")).isDisplayed());
    Select abcSupplier = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input")));
    /*abcSupplier.selectByIndex(17);*/
    abcSupplier.selectByVisibleText("TBD");
}
```

HTMl Code:

```html
<input 
    name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$orderDeliveryControl$lstDelivery$ctrl0$deliveryPanelBar$i0$lstOrderRequestItems$ctrl0$deliveryDetailControl$lstDeliveryLineItem$ctrl0$lineItemControl$lstBuyLineItems$ctrl0$buyLineItemControl$cmbSupplier" 
    type="text"
    class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate Required_Field_Control Required_Field_Control_Off"   
    id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input"
    value="Mansfield Oil Company of Gainesville Inc" 
    autocomplete="off">
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is HTML code?

Comment: Could you replace these "soMuchLoooongIdsAndNames" with something shorter (like "id", "myid", etc.) to improve readability of your code? Also there's no `select` in your HTML, only `input`. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: id is `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input` — seriously?

Answer (score 1):

Examine this line:

```
Select abcSupplier = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_orderDeliveryControl_lstDelivery_ctrl0_deliveryPanelBar_i0_lstOrderRequestItems_ctrl0_deliveryDetailControl_lstDeliveryLineItem_ctrl0_lineItemControl_lstBuyLineItems_ctrl0_buyLineItemControl_cmbSupplier_Input")));
```

You are expecting element of type `Select` but path that you are sending to function `findElement` ends by `Input`. IMHO this clearly hints that something is wrong either in your ID or in expected element type. It is impossible to give you more concrete answer since only you know the exact structure of HTML document you are working with. But you have to  provide correct ID and treat element according to its actual type.